# Remove duplicates with a criteria

Tags: sql, duplicates

What I am trying to do is remove a duplicate row where the ID is a duplicate and a column in that row equals null.

```
ex:
id - website
1, www.domain.com
1, null
1, null
2, www.test.com
2, null
```

What it should be:

```
1, www.domain.com
2, www.test.com
```

So what I am doing, is simply joining two tables together, and adding in the results, but the issue is that one table has several records for one ID, so there will be extra rows per ID containing a null value. How can I remove the duplicate records from the query when an ID has more than one row and the row equals null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the duplicates have `NULL`, then you don't need `distinct` at all:

```
select id, website
from table t
where website is not null;
```

Removing the `distinct` (if it is not necessary) improves performance.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, website
FROM your_table
WHERE website IS NOT NULL
```